# Child Navigation Bar Not Showing

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I've created two ViewControllers and both of their navigation bars are not displaying when I go to these pages. Please see the layouts below.

[image]

When I run the app, 'History' and 'Top Rated' won't show up. Instead, the navigation bar in the Tab Bar Controller will show up. (I'm using swift)

Comment: Why are you adding nav bars? Just push the view controllers onto a navigation controller.

Comment: @rmaddy What do you mean by pushing view controllers onto nav controller? What I want to do is to have different navigation bar contents in each view controller.

Comment: Your hierarchy doesn't make sense. The tab bar controller will be under the navigation controller but each of the tab bars controllers won't be.  You probably want your tab bar to be the root controller and then embed the top rated and history view controllers in their own navigationController's (assuming you want to have a navigation stack for each of them)

Comment: There are two was to solve it... First ist to make the NavControllers Navbar not trasnlucent, the Second is, set a magrin to you other navbars as high as the Controllers nacbsrs

Comment: @Paulw11 I tried to set the tab view controller as the root and it works! Thanks for the help.